# How to read data from excel file in C++/VC 6.0 without MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Have to read data from MS Excel File, the data contains name DOB as well as some numeric values...

Comment: If you convert your excel to a csv file, it will be a normal file I/O.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, given this "spec" you can use either MS-COM or VBA for this. C++ COM  example follows. Of course if you are using a newer version with XML storage it just became a lot less complicated. It's XML after all. :-)

```
   // Initialize COM for this thread...
   CoInitialize(NULL);

   // Get CLSID for our server...
   CLSID clsid;
   HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Excel.Application", &clsid);

   if(FAILED(hr)) {

      ::MessageBox(NULL, "CLSIDFromProgID() failed", "Error", 0x10010);
      return -1;
   }

   // Start server and get IDispatch...
   IDispatch *pXlApp;
   hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pXlApp);
   if(FAILED(hr)) {
      ::MessageBox(NULL, "Excel not registered properly", "Error", 0x10010);
      return -2;
   }

   // Make it visible (i.e. app.visible = 1)
   {

      VARIANT x;
      x.vt = VT_I4;
      x.lVal = 1;
      AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, pXlApp, L"Visible", 1, x);
   }

   // Get Workbooks collection
   IDispatch *pXlBooks;
   {
      VARIANT result;
      VariantInit(&result);
      AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlApp, L"Workbooks", 0);
      pXlBooks = result.pdispVal;
   }

   // Call Workbooks.Add() to get a new workbook...
   IDispatch *pXlBook;
   {
      VARIANT result;
      VariantInit(&result);
      AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlBooks, L"Add", 0);
      pXlBook = result.pdispVal;
   }

   // Create a 15x15 safearray of variants...
   VARIANT arr;
   arr.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
   {
      SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
      sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 15;
      sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 15;
      arr.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);
   }

   // Fill safearray with some values...
   for(int i=1; iRelease();
   pXlSheet->Release();
   pXlBook->Release();
   pXlBooks->Release();
   pXlApp->Release();
   VariantClear(&arr);

   // Uninitialize COM for this thread...
   CoUninitialize();
```

[**More here.**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q216686/)

Given the section tags we're in, I'll not show a VBA example, but if needed search for "VBA open Excel code" you'll get a lot of example code.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice [document](http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf) the structure (various BIFF formats)